# How to delete a large number of temporary files on my external hard drive?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, file-management, rm, temporary-files

I'm currently processing a series of large data files (150+ GB) on my home laptop (a 2015 MacBook running MacOS Catalina 10.15.3). I ran into the issue where a particular program wouldn't finish executing because it couldn't generate temp files for the process (usually, on similar size data sets on my more powerful work computer, the temp files would all collapse into one processed data file). I changed the file descriptor limit to allow for a larger number of temp files momentarily and its caused the buildup of over 1E6 temp files that I can no longer access.

I'm working on the files while they're in my external hard drive (I don't have nearly enough space on my laptop), but the temp files nearly maxed out my hard drive so I had to cancel the program. Now, I'm no longer able to access the folder they're stored in. I can't open the folder -- the files won't populate the Finder. I can't use the command line to run any 'find' and 'delete' functions. I can't use the rm function either. In all cases, the RAM comes close to maxing out on my laptop and automatically cancels the operation.

Is there anyway to delete these temp files off of my hard drive? It's nearly 200 GB of temp files and the file extension is .sort.bam

If you have ANY suggestions, I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is that external HDD partitioned and formatted? HFS+ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you have tried find + xargs, but I'm offering this first suggestion because

1. It has saved my bacon more than once,
2. You may have tried something slightly different (e.g. 'find /foldername/*.sort.bam', which is not the same at all, and
3. Someone else may not be familiar with the command.

My first suggestion is:

```
find /foldername -name \*.sort.bam -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Caveats:

- It should work, BUT, it will probably take a LONG time for a large number of files.
- However, if you kill it, and run it again, it will pick up where it left off.
- See the bottom for ways to look for signs this command is actually doing something, e.g. from another window, since it won't provide any output by default.
- If you get permissions errors, you probably need to run each command (find and xargs) with sudo.

If that won't work (I could imagine it), then I suggest:

First, try to find the files in that folder that you want to retain, if any.  Ideally you remember the names of those files, or you can discover them.  You probably can't use 'ls' or tab completion in the shell to figure them out anymore; the directory is too full for those to complete in sane amounts of time.

Presumably you can't use 'find' with a '-name ' either (otherwise the above command would work)

If you have a list of files, you can probably do:

```
cp <exact filename> <target directory>
```

That should work almost regardless of how full the directory is (it isn't guaranteed to be fast though).

If you don't have a list of files, then they might be gone now.

Assuming you've given up on the rest of the files in the directory, you can try:

```
find /brokenDirectory -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This is ALSO not guaranteed to be fast.  It may work better without the filename filter, and should pick up where it leaves off if it does work.

If all else fails, dust off and nuke it from orbit:

- On a new partition or disk, create a copy of every file on the partition that is NOT in that folder.  This might be hard; many tools don't have an easy: "except this one" option.
- Use a low-level tool to erase the entire partition with the problem folder, so that it can be recreated empty.

I suggest using 'top' 'iostat' and 'df' (don't forget 'df -i' to watch the number of inodes in use decrease if your filesystem does that) and 'dstat' as potentially useful tools to confirm that the find+xargs is actually doing something.

Comment: Sigh, I tried all of the options, nothing would even copy unfortunately. I had to nuke the hard drive. I have the data stored in the cloud but its a pain to download. I really appreciate all of your help!